# cuando uso input(), por defecto me pide numeros, pero me deberia pedir strings

Tags: python

titulo1 = input("Proporcione el titulo del libro ")
File "", line 1
el principito
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: ¿Solo te da problema si hay espacios, verdad?

Comment: me da error al querer usar comas para concatenar

Comment: Has intentado con la función raw_input  ?

Comment: ahi me funciono!

Comment: Recuerda que debes especificar la versión de python con la que trabajas

Answer (score 0):

Para los inpus que incluyan comas usaremos la función:

```
titulo = raw_input("Proporcione el titulo del libro ")
```

Facilmente podemos formatar el texto introducido en el caso de que queramos crear una lista a partir de la enumeración introducida.

```
list = str.split (",")
print "list: ", list
```